# There is a weird white line on my monitor glass (not on my screen)

Tags: display, desktop-computer

Just bought a new monitor and when I was checking for stuck pixels I noticed a thick white line on the glass of the monitor. It is only visible when light shines directly on the monitor and only when it's either showing solid black or is turned off. Does anyone know what it is? I tried gently pressing on it to see if it would react but nothing happened. It doesnt affect the actual image in any way but I'm worried it might indicate that something is wrong. The picture below is the best angle I managed to get.

[image: picture]

Comment: Is the violet light the reflection of something (e.g. of your keyboard)?

Comment: What happens if you wet your finger and touch the line gently? does it change shape, or do you feel a weird texture on your fingers? This will determine if the problem is on the outside of the screen or the inside.

Comment: Looks like a rupture or massive scratch in some inner layer of the display.

Answer (score 0):

press `windows key + PrtSc` and then open clipboard by pressing `windows key + v` if the white line shows up on the screenshot you took, then it is a software problem i.e. problem with one of your device drivers.
possible fixes:

1. Go to setting>Update & security and see if there are any updates. This usually works for most people. if not continue reading.
2. go to device manager. To do that, press `windows key + r` to open the run wizard, then, type 'devmgmt.msc'(no quote marks), then, select Display adapter, right click on any of the adapters and select 'update driver'.

if the white line `does not` show up on the screenshot, then it is definitely a hardware problem.
Usually such lines mean that the plastic(yes plastic) protective layer that is located just beneath the screen surface has been bent. It could be due to heat or due to bending of monitor. If that is the case then I suggest you take it to your nearest service guy and get iit fixed.
P.S: Do not try to do anything more to your monitor since monitors are still components of  high delicacy. And must be handled by professionals only

Comment: They see the line with the screen off. How can this be a software problem? So only the last paragraph applies.